# Why doesn't the SerialPort class have an RIHolding property?

Tags: .net, serial-port, api-design

Simple question. The .NET [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport) class has the following properties for getting serial input lines:

- [`CDHolding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.cdholding) - Gets the state of the Carrier Detect line for the port.
- [`CtsHolding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.ctsholding) - Gets the state of the Clear-to-Send line.
- [`DsrHolding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dsrholding) - Gets the state of the Data Set Ready (DSR) signal.

Note `RIHolding` is missing.

Additionally, it has the [`PinChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.pinchanged) event. That provides a [`SerialPinChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialpinchange) enum value, which has the following members, and *does include* one for Ring:

- `CtsChanged` - The Clear to Send (CTS) signal changed state...
- `DsrChanged` -The Data Set Ready (DSR) signal changed state...
- `CDChanged` - The Carrier Detect (CD) signal changed state...
- `Ring` - A ring indicator was detected.
- `Break` - A break was detected on input.

So my question is, why is there not an `RIHolding` property?

---

If we look at the internal `SerialStream` class, we see that `CDHolding`, `CtsHolding`, and `DsrHolding` are all implemented by a call to the Win32 [`GetCommModemStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363258.aspx) function. His `lpModemStat` output values are one of the following:

- **`MS_CTS_ON`** `0x0010` The CTS (clear-to-send) signal is on.
- **`MS_DSR_ON`** `0x0020` The DSR (data-set-ready) signal is on.
- **`MS_RING_ON`** `0x0040` The ring indicator signal is on.
- **`MS_RLSD_ON`** `0x0080` The RLSD (receive-line-signal-detect) signal is on. *(This maps to `CDHolding`)*

So, it seems that it would have been trivial to add an `RIHolding` property that just looks at bit 6. Why was this left out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's by nature a transient signal due to the ring signal cadence.  If it is on then it is not going to stay on for very long.  2 seconds in the USA, 400 msec in the UK for example.  So the state of signal doesn't mean much, it is timing dependent and worse case you'll always observe it off when you are really unlucky.  You'd better catch it when it turns on, thus PinChanged reports it.

Comment: But if you're trying to show it, in a GUI for example, 400 ms is plenty of time.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation of *why* it was left out. Doesn't make me any happier about it, though :-)

Comment: In many implementations RI signal is generating a hardware interrupt thus eliminating the polling process.